# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

this error keeps popping up left, right, and center in my code. it's really annoying. till now, I've fixed them all but i can't seem to be able to fix this one.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\da.py", line 31, in <module>
if (number > 1):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

the code itself:

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
def add_text():
    global number
    number = num_textbox.get()
    print(number)
root = Tk()
root.title("Number Cent Divider")
root.geometry("330x85")
num_col_mat = Label(root, text="Your number:")
num_col_mat.pack()
num_textbox = Entry(root, bd=1)
num_textbox.pack()
enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter", command=add_text)
enter_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
if (number[-1] == 5 or number[-1] == 0):
    number / 5
    int(number)
    if (number > 1):
        answer = "\number 5 cent coins"
        str(number)
        popup()
    else:
        answer = "\number 5 cent coin"
        str(number)
        popup()
else:
    int(number)
    if (number > 1):
        answer = "\number 1 cent coins"
        str(number)
        popup()
    else:
        answer = "\number 1 cent coin"
        str(number)
        popup()
def popup():
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("answer")
    answer = Label(popup, text=answer)
    answer.pack
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Ok", command=popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
```

any help would be appreciated since this error does not want to get fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number` is a `str`, so you first need to convert it to a number. E.g.:

```
if int(number) > 1
```

Writing `int(number)` on a line by itself doesn't do anything... it just returns a number, which is then ignored. You could use `number = int(number)` if you wanted to store the result in the `number` variable.

Consider using `number = int(num_textbox.get())` to get the conversion out of the way up front. (But note that if the contents of that text box is not a valid number, you'll get an exception.)

Comment: thanks. learned something new. i'll close the question when it lets me. (11 mins)